# Define the interval in which a single measurement must be using statistical analysis

Tags: probability, statistics

I designed a sensor which produces an output voltage which is linear to an input temperature. To test the sensor in production, the sensor is exposed to a known and controlled temperature. Assuming that the input test temperature is perfect, how can I determine the pass/fail range to use in production for all manufactured sensors based on statistical analysis of $N$ sensors?

At the moment, I have randomly measured the output voltage of $N=50$ sensors at a known temperature and calculated the mean and standard deviation based on this sample set. Next, I decided that the pass/fail range should be $\mu \pm 3\sigma$, where $\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation, to account for $99.7\%$ of all cases.

I feel that my method is incorrect because I don't account for the sample size.

Does anyone know if I'm doing this correctly or should I be using a different method?

Answer (score 1):

The method that BruceET suggested seems very promising but the results I get is a little strange.

Here is an example of what I have:

1. n  =  20
2. S  = 0.015983
3. /x = 0.5779
4. t = 2.093024 (probability = 0.975, degrees of freedom = 20-1)
5. calculated interval min value = 0.57042
6. calculated interval max value = 0.58538
7. interval (0.57042, 0.58538)

This feels strange because most of my raw sample data that produced the S and /x values are outside the calculated interval:

1. 0.586 (out)
2. 0.595 (out)
3. 0.585 (in)
4. 0.558 (out)
5. 0.583 (in)
6. 0.569 (out)
7. 0.564 (out)
8. 0.572 (in)
9. 0.592 (out)
10. 0.559 (out)
11. 0.562 (out)
12. 0.547 (out)
13. 0.560 (out)
14. 0.594 (out)
15. 0.588 (out)
16. 0.599 (out)
17. 0.575 (in)
18. 0.587 (out)
19. 0.605 (out)
20. 0.578 (in)

I must be doing something wrong or I'm just not understanding something.

Comment: As suggested in the above thread comments by BruceET, I used the prediction interval which seems to be the correct approach for my application. The prediction interval is an estimate of an interval in which a future observation will fall. I highly recommend you checkout wiki about prediction interval for further details.

Answer (score 0):

The range of allowable values for a sensor to 'pass' may be
determined by a number of considerations or constraints that
have nothing to do with your sample.

You can make a 95% confidence interval for the true voltage
during your experiment based on $n = 50$ observations:
$$\bar X \pm t^*S/\sqrt{50},$$
where $\bar X$ is the average (sample mean) of fifty, $S$ is the sample standard deviation, and $t^* \approx 2.0$ cuts probability $0.025 = 2.5\%$ from the upper tail of Student's t distribution with
$n-1=49$ degrees of freedom (a symmetrical distribution). You can get the value of $t^*$ from printed tables of Student t distributions or from software (e.g., R) as shown below.

```
qt(.975, 49)
[1] 2.009575
```

In particular, if your sample is as the one below (simulated in R),
then the 95% CI is $(111.7, 112.3).$

```
set.seed(918)
x = rnorm(50, 112, 1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  109.4   111.3   112.0   112.0   112.5   114.7 
[1] 1.110945  # sample SD

t.test(x)$conf.int
[1] 111.6581 112.2896
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

However, independently of your experiment, people buying your sensor may want to feel sure that
voltages near 112 measured in the conditions you specify
should be accurate within $\pm 0.1.$

Comment: Thank you BruceET for the comprehensive answer. This was very helpful to point me in the right direction. I have attempted to apply your suggested method using excel as my primary computational tool. When testing it out, I find that the interval I get is very small and even more strange is that the bulk of my raw sample data is actually outside the range. I will elaborate my findings in this thread.

Comment: Notice that in my example both endpoints of the CI $(111.7,112.3)$ lie inside the Lower and Upper quartiles. This says that _over half_ of the individual observations lie outside the CI. (Don't know if that's the 'bulk' of them according to your perspective.) A CI Is not trying to _predict_ individual observations, but to _estimate_ the population mean.// If you want an interval that is pretty sure to contain a future observation, that's a different thing. Maybe you want prediction interval $\bar X \pm t^*S\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{50}}.$// Best to be absolutely clear what your objective is.

Comment: OK, I just tested using the prediction interval and the results make more sense. All my samples are now within the interval. My apologies if my question was not properly formulated. Yes, I'm essentially trying to provide a PASS/FAIL range to our production team when they test the output voltage when the system is within known and controlled conditions. I will update this thread with my findings for completeness.  Many thanks BruceET!

Comment: But I don't see how you can make promises to people who buy your sensor what kinds of error they will get. You don't know the conditions under which it will be used by others.

Comment: BruceET, this senor and test is only used on a sub-assembly and not the fully completed device. We simply wanted a go/no-go test to ensure that the sub-assembly is in working order before it's mounted into the final system. Because of the nature of the system, we actually do know the existing conditions. Once the sub-assembly is installed, the full system is comprehensively tested to ensure it's within expected tolerances. I hope this clarifies things a little more.